# Couldn't click on dialog with casperjs

Tags: casperjs

This is my code I would like to accept  confirm dialog  but I couldn't catch dialog however I click on correct selector.  I expect that where dialog window appeared  the  popup.loaded event will be triggered.

which  [image]:

```
 casper.test.begin('Sign up with Yahoo' , 2 , function(test) {   

casper.on('popup.loaded', function () {
 this.echo("HELLOOPOPUP")
});

x=require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.start("file:///home/sb/mytest/casperlogin-master/caspertest/ak.html" , function() {

this.wait(3000, function() {    
this.on('popup.loaded', function () {
   this.echo("HELLOOPOPUP")
});


this.click(x('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[11]/div/button'));    
});

    this.wait(2000, function() {

this.setFilter('page.confirm', function(message) {
    return true;
});
})

});


});
 casper.run(function() {
 });
```

Mark up link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Nj-vLTRyujTm1zeGdZbmVmcnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include the markup of the page in your question. An image is helpful, but it can't be used to validate the XPath expression. Have you taken a screenshot to see if the correct page is opened? I see no validation code in you code snippet. Also, code indentation wouldn't hurt.

Comment: `casper.on()` and `casper.setFilter()` are basically event handlers, so you should register the handlers *before* you do the action that might invoke the event.

Comment: attached mark up  link

Comment: Question must be self-contained. If the link breaks then the question and potential answers lose all value. You need to include important information in the question itself.